# How to compile JNI shared library without Android Studio and with dependencies inside

Tags: android, java-native-interface

I want to create a JNI shared library which uses libc functions without having to depend on Android Studio

I was able to build and load the shared library by using the jni.h header I found inside the android ndk, and exporting the JNI_OnLoad function

But when I use libc functions, it links the libc library to a path that doesn't exist in the target android device, for example

libtest.so links to `/lib32/libc.so.6` but in the android device libc's path is `/system/lib/libc.so`

So how can I correctly link my library to libc's path in the target device or how can I pack the dependencies inside my shared library

PS: I'm using ubuntu 18, gcc and a simple makefile, thanks!

Comment: If someone has the same question here is what I finally did: I have to make a standalone toolchain (https://developer.android.com/ndk/guides/standalone_toolchain)

Answer (score 1):

You should use `ndk-build` to compile jni sources.  It can be called from `ant`

Comment: I am gonna setup an Android.mk file to try with `ndk-build`, thanks